# CSV Import status in Netsuite

Tags: netsuite

I am creating a task using Scheduled script and submitting the task. Now once I submit the job I want to know the status or the message once the job is finished or completed. if it is having any errors then I want to get the CSV response file.

```
var mrTask = task.create({
        taskType: task.TaskType.CSV_IMPORT,
        importFile: FileID,
        mappingId: mappingID
        })
var myTaskId = mrTask.submit();
var taskStatus = task.checkStatus({
        taskId: myTaskId
        });
```

I am using `taskStatus.status` but it is always showing PENDING in logs even if job is complete, or it is having errors

- I wanted the response message for ex. "3 of 3 records imported successfully"
- I wanted the csv response file which I can save in NetSuite file-cabinet

Comment: The submit does not wait for the task to complete so your posted code checks the status long before it has a chance to run.

Answer (score 0):

You will get always **pending** because  this task enters into a Queue to process even if is the only one on it.